# IgnoresListHandling for Protobuf-net v2

Tags: c#, serialization, .net-4.0, protobuf-net

I'm working with protobuf-net v2 r480 (to the best of my understanding...).

**Question:**

How can I get protobuf-net to ignore list handling when the class with the list handling (`FileTree`) is a field of another class (`MyRandomStuff`)?

**Background:**

I have a FileTree class (which I previously described [here on StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8362571/force-protobuf-net-to-ignore-ienumerable-icollection-interfaces)) which implements `ICollection<MyFileInfo>`, `IEnumerable<MyFileInfo>`, `IEnumerable`, and a few other interfaces. I have tagged the `FileTree` class with `[ProtoContract(IgnoreListHandling = true)]`. The `FileTree` class itself serializes beautifully.

The problem I am having is with `MyRandomStuff` class, which has a `FileTree` field. When I tag that field with "`[ProtoIgnore]`", the instance of `MyRandomStuff`serializes just fine. However, when I include the `FileTree` field via "`[ProtoMember(2)]`", serialization fails with a message that the `MyFileInfo` object needs to have a parameterless constructor. I have intentionally setup my code so that `MyFileInfo` is never serializable. (Instead, `FileTree` creates the relevant `MyFileInfo` objects during deserialization).

Unfortunately, I don't have a quick sample that I can send if it is a bug. I have a work-around already, but I thought maybe I'd ask here if I'm just doing something incorrectly (like tagging, or using an out-of-date version of protobuf).

Comment: No, that isn't the expected behaviour. No, you are not doing anything wrong. Have repro - my first-try fix will take some tweaking as it impacts some tests, need to look why. Applies only to a point in time, though, so closing the question *here*. Will be fixed soon.

Comment: @MarcGravell This question sounds nearly identical to a problem I'm currently having, except that I'm being told it's "Unable to resolve a suitable Add method." Adding `IgnoreListHandling = true` allowed me to serialize struct `A`, but the error persists when trying to serialize struct `B`, which has two fields of struct `A`. Removing `IEnumerable<T>` from struct `A` allows both `A` and `B` to serialize.

Comment: @Dan I'll have to investigate

Comment: @MarcGravell Just @ me if you need more info to reproduce.

Comment: @Dan if you happen to *have* a small self-contained repro, it would save me some time - but I'm not saying you should g out of your way to create one.

Comment: @MarcGravell I narrowed down the problem to struct `A`'s indexer property. I reproduced the error succinctly here: http://dl.dropbox.com/u/832464/Code/SO9575661.zip